# Game theory row elimination

Tags: proof-explanation, game-theory

I have a zero-sum game described by $$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 8\\
4 & 2\\
3 & 5
\end{pmatrix} $$

where the player 1 selects the row and he wants to maximize the utility and the player 2 selects the column and he wants to minimize the utility. In the solutions the professor starts by deleting the first row because he says that it is never selected by player 1. Can someone tell me why I can delete the first row?

Comment: Are you sure those are the correct numbers?  I could see justifying deleting the first row if it were $\begin{bmatrix}1&\color{red}{2}\\4&\color{red}{8}\\3&5\end{bmatrix}$ since in such a scenario regardless what player 2 picks player 1 would have had a better outcome in any other row other than the first

Comment: I wrote exactly the text of the exercise, in fact after deleting the first row I get the same result of the professor about the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2\\
3 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: optimal strategy is $((0,\frac12,\frac12),(\frac34,\frac14))$ and the value of the game is $\frac72$

Comment: "*I wrote exactly the text of the exercise*"... "*Can someone tell me why I can delete the first row?*"  If you did not make a typo yourself in copying then perhaps your professor had made a typo or mistake... there is no justification with the numbers as given to have deleted the first row, an optimal strategy might still have involved the first row.

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed I couldn't find a reason!

Comment: I recommend [PatrickJMT's video on the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtfpkuB-SGw)

Comment: As a final aside from me, after solving, we do get the optimal strategy is as you say, but to have arrived at that still required keeping the first row in our calculations.  Deleting a row is allowed if there is some other row with every entry larger than each corresponding entry in our row we are looking to delete.  $8$ is not smaller than the corresponding entries in the other rows so there was no row which "dominated" the first row thanks to this.

Comment: If the matrix were instead $\begin{bmatrix}1&11\\4&2\\3&5\end{bmatrix}$ then an equally valid optimal strategy for player $1$ would have been $(\frac{1}{6},\frac{5}{6},0)$ with the same value for the game and same optimal strategy for player 2 and the first row would in fact have been a part of an optimal winning strategy for player $1$.  It happens to not be used in your original matrix because the numbers happen to have worked out that way.  If instead of $11$ it were even larger then the value of the game increases.